# Raspberry Pi not shown under ethernet connections

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, pi-zero-w

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero W with my laptop via a USB to mini USB cable. I have made the changes in `cmdline.txt`, `config.txt` and a blank file named `ssh` in boot folder. However, when I connect the board to the laptop via the cable, there isn't any new connection found in Windows Network Connections. I also checked the available devices under 'Other Devices' in Windows Device Manager, but there weren't any Ethernet Devices detected.

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: you set up the pi0 with gadget g_ether and use the power socket to connect to the pc?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes

Comment: Also, my config.txt file looks a bit different than the ones shown in tutorials. Mine has some extra lines written.

Comment: If you are using the power socket on the zero then it will not work unless you have a second USB cable plugged in as well.  Only the USB port marked 'USB' (closest to the HDMI out) will support Ethernet.  The one closest to the edge (marked 'PWR') is power only.  The Pi can be powered from the USB port while it is being used for Ethernet by the same cable.

Comment: @Andrew - I thought "gadget mode" used the power socket - and OP wants ethernet over OTG not over a USB ethernet adapter

Comment: @JaromandaX - baffled OTG is USB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go and the Zero power port does not have the data pins enabled - it is literally power only.  The other port can both power the Zero (and zero W) and provided OTG / data RPF specs state Micro USB OTG port and Micro USB power I assumed OP was doing https://desertbot.io/blog/headless-pi-zero-ssh-access-over-usb-windows  maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm probably wrong, sorry